# String array without initial size gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I was just checking some OCJP questions and came across this difference during String array initialization and exceptions.

**Case 1**

```
try {
    String[][] b = new String[10][10]; // 1
    System.out.println(b[0][0]);       // 2
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception during array 'b' initialization");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Case 2**

```
try {
    String[][] a = new String[10][]; // 3
    System.out.println(a[0][0]);     // 4
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception during array 'a' initialization");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Line 2 does not throw any exception whereas line 4 throws a null pointer exception.
Line 2 does output the value as `null` though.

Does java have a difference in default values for initialization when the size of an array is specified and when its not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sets the type of `a`, as array of arrays :

```
String[][] a
```

When you write

```
String[][] a = new String[10][];
```

you initialize the external array, but you don't create the internal arrays, so that `a[0]` is `null`.

When you write

```
String[][] b = new String[10][10];
```

the runtime creates also the internal arrays. It's described [here in the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) :

> At run time, evaluation of an array creation expression behaves as
>   follows:
>
> If there are no dimension expressions, then there must be an array
>   initializer.
>
> A newly allocated array will be initialized with the values provided
>   by the array initializer as described in §10.6.
>
> The value of the array initializer becomes the value of the array
>   creation expression.
>
> Otherwise, there is no array initializer, and:
>
> First, the dimension expressions are evaluated, left-to-right. If any
>   of the expression evaluations completes abruptly, the expressions to
>   the right of it are not evaluated.
>
> Next, the values of the dimension expressions are checked. If the
>   value of any DimExpr expression is less than zero, then a
>   NegativeArraySizeException is thrown.
>
> Next, space is allocated for the new array. If there is insufficient
>   space to allocate the array, evaluation of the array creation
>   expression completes abruptly by throwing an OutOfMemoryError.
>
> Then, if a single DimExpr appears, a one-dimensional array is created
>   of the specified length, and each component of the array is
>   initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).
>
> Otherwise, if n DimExpr expressions appear, then array creation
>   effectively executes a set of nested loops of depth n-1 to create the
>   implied arrays of arrays.
>
> A multidimensional array need not have arrays of the same length at
>   each level.

Comment: `and each component of the array is initialized to its default value`
so Line 3 should assign 10 `1-D arrays` and assign `null` as value to each of its elements right? The same as it happens for Line 1 as well. Am i right?

Comment: It assigns null to `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc. While line 1 assigns null to `b[0][0]`, `b[0][1]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] a = new String[3][];
```

is equivalent to:

```
String[] a1 = null;
String[] a2 = null;
String[] a3 = null;
String[][] a = {a1, a2, a3};
```

and `a[0][0]` is similar to `a1[0]` which throws NPE.

---

You have two options here:

- Either define the array as:

```
String[][] a = new String[3][3];
```

- Or create new arrays inside `a`:

```
a[0] = new String[2];
a[1] = new String[4];
a[2] = new String[3];
```

Note that using the latter approach you will be able to have different sizes for the internal arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Good discovery. When you initialize a 2D array with both parameters, what happens is:

```
String[][] a = new String[5][5]
```

[image: 2D Array with both bounds]

But when you *don't* specify the second bound, what happens is:

```
String[][] a = new String[5][];
```

[image: 2D Array with no inner bound]

In your line 4, you get the exact NullPointerException because:

```
String[][] a = new String[10][];
System.out.println(a[0][0]); // << a[0] is null!
```

But why would you even need this behavior? Its quite simple. It is for the cases where each element in a two-dimensional array can have different number of elements. The potential use case scenario is:

[image]

And there are pretty good use cases for this kind of behavior, such as Priority Queues (each priority can have a different number of items in queue), Hash table (the overflow part of it), etc.